# An issue installing MySQL 5.5 on clean Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to install `mysql-server` and `libmysqlclient-dev` on clean Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, but I get an error:

```
131031 13:31:15 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
    start: Job failed to start
    invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
    dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
     mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
      Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                               ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     mysql-server-5.5
     mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Full traceback:

```
$ dpkg -S etc/mysql
mysql-common: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
mysql-server-5.5: /etc/mysql/debian-start
mysql-common, mysql-server-5.5: /etc/mysql/conf.d
mysql-server-5.5: /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
mysql-common, mysql-server-5.5: /etc/mysql
$ sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common
apt-get: /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libdbd-mysql-perl* libmysqlclient-dev* libmysqlclient18* mysql-client-5.5*
  mysql-common* mysql-server* mysql-server-5.5*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 7 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 73.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? yes
(Reading database ... 72906 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server ...
Removing mysql-server-5.5 ...
Purging configuration files for mysql-server-5.5 ...
Removing mysql-client-5.5 ...
Removing libdbd-mysql-perl ...
Removing libmysqlclient-dev ...
Removing libmysqlclient18 ...
Purging configuration files for libmysqlclient18 ...
Removing mysql-common ...
Purging configuration files for mysql-common ...
dpkg: warning: while removing mysql-common, directory '/etc/mysql' not empty so not removed.
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
$ dpkg -S etc/mysql
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *etc/mysql*.
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-5.6.14-debian6.0-x86_64.deb 
(Reading database ... 72664 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mysql 5.6.14 (using mysql-5.6.14-debian6.0-x86_64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mysql ...
Setting up mysql (5.6.14) ...
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
apt-get: /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common
  mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
Recommended packages:
  libhtml-template-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/18.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 67.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
apt-extracttemplates: /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 72664 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-common (from .../mysql-common_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient18.
Unpacking libmysqlclient18 (from .../libmysqlclient18_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (from .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.020-1build2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.5.
Unpacking mysql-client-5.5 (from .../mysql-client-5.5_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
(Reading database ... 72750 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libmysqlclient18 (5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.020-1build2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
131031 13:31:15 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                           ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Killing mysql processes and running

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken
```

did the trick for me. Probably purge is needed before too, though.

https://serverfault.com/a/296928/124523